# fancybox for image gallery in zend

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I am working on a project in  zend where I need to display the photos uploaded in image gallery, but I don't know how to implement that.
Code of view where uses'r data is displayed...

profile.phtml

```
    <html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/demo.css" type="text/css" >
    <link href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js"></script></head>    
    <a href='<?php $i=$this->basePath()."/../project/login/logout"; echo $i; ?>'>Click here to logout</a></font>
      <section>
    <?php 
    $a=$this->abc;
    $c=$a['cityname'];  
    ?>
    <p><b>You are viewing full profile of <?php echo $a['name'];?></b></p>
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab" >General Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2"  data-toggle="tab">Basic Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3"  data-toggle="tab">Education Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4"  data-toggle="tab">Occupation Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5"  data-toggle="tab">Family Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6"  data-toggle="tab">Kundli Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-7"  data-toggle="tab">Other Deatils</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#tabs-8"  data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>   
    </ul>


    <?php 
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,array('controller'=>'Search', 'action' =>'confirm')));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $form->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');   
    ?>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">    
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-8">   
    <h3><center>Photos</center></h3>            
    <table   class="table a8">
    <tr><td><a href="confirm?id=<?php echo $a['memcode'];?> "> </td></tr>
    <tr><th>Photos</th><td>
    <div >
        <a href="<?php echo $this->basePath("upload/".$a['imageupload']);?>" rel="gallery">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->basePath("upload/".$a['imageupload']);?>" height="50px" width="50px" alt="Description here">
        </a>

    </div>
</table>
    </div>  
    </section>
```

Comment: There's not enough details to answer this question, what is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I am working on a matrimonial project,for that user will register into our site and upload their photos.I want the photos to be saved and when any other user view their profile the photos will be displayed as in image gallery i.e. fancybox through jquery

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my problem.
I have downloaded the fancybox plugin from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ and copied the css and js files in relevant folder.

### And then I wrote this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css"><script src="/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            beforeShow : function() {
                var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

                this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

                this.title = alt;
            }
        });
        });
            </script>

<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="First picture"/></a>
```